# Why am I unable to get Site.State for an FTP site, when using Microsoft.Web.Administration?

Tags: c#, iis

Using the following C# code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

namespace getftpstate
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      ServerManager manager = new ServerManager();
      foreach (Site site in manager.Sites)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("name: " + site.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("state: " + site.State);
        Console.WriteLine("----");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
C:\projects\testiisftp\getftpstate\getftpstate\bin\Debug>getftpstate.exe
name: Default Web Site
state: Stopped
----
name: Default FTP Site

Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800710D8): T
he object identifier does not represent a valid object. (Exception from HRESULT:
 0x800710D8)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostProperty.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement.GetPropertyValue(IAppHos
tProperty property)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site.get_State()
   at getftpstate.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\projects\testiisftp\getftpst
ate\getftpstate\Program.cs:line 17
```

Any ideas why I might be seeing the above 0x800710D8 COM error? I'm able to manage the FTP site just fine using IIS manager (I can start, stop, change settings, etc).

Comment: I've tried to use WMI as a work around, but guess what, FTP sites are stored under the W3SVC node in the IIS metabase (when access through WMI), and the site's ServerState returns always 4 for FTP sites, which means "Stopped" according to the documentation (even though it's showing as Started in IIS manager). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524905(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Also, I have raised this on MS connect (please upvote if this affects you): https://connect.microsoft.com/WindowsServerFeedback/feedback/details/566045/comexception-when-accessing-site-state-for-an-ftp-site-using-microsoft-web-administration

Comment: Just tried to start and stop the FTP site via both MWA and WMI; neither worked, with similar results. However, instead of throwing an exception, WMI just does nothing silently.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing to clarify is that `Site.State` is a property to get the state of the HTTP protocol and for that reason my guess is that the site that is throwing that exception is probably NOT an HTTP site.

If you want to get the FTP state you need to do is:

```
int ftpState = Site.GetChildElement("ftpServer")["state"]
```

You can verify if a site is HTTP or not by inspecting the Site.Bindings and looking for the Protocol property, if it does not have HTTP or HTTPS you will get the exception above which you could safely ignore.

For more information: [IIS.net FTP Settings / Sample Code](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites/site/ftpServer#006)

Comment: Aha, interesting idea. Hmm, though I'm sure I tried accessing it in a similar way -- but I will give this a try anyway. Also I have unmarked my answer accordingly (hopefully I can delete it if you're right).

Comment: Try it out, I do know a bit about MWA (I wrote it :) ) so let me know if it does not work, or if you run into other issue.

Comment: Thanks CarolsAg! The`GetChildElement("ftpServer")` indeed does allow you to access the FTP site methods. Great link, too.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is that this is just a bug in the Microsoft IIS API that we have to live with. I've opened a bug report on MS connect which has had 2 upvotes, however MS have shown no interest in this (and I doubt they will any time soon).

I don't believe there is a workaround for getting the actual state (as the question asks). Some have suggested that I should probe port 21, but this only tells me if there is *an* FTP server running, not *what* FTP server is running (as you can have multiple sites) -- so in some cases, this approach is completely useless.

The workaround to *stopping and starting* the site (which also causes a similar error) is to set auto-start to false on the FTP site and restart IIS (it's not great, but it works just fine).